# How do deploy in azure app-service web-apps with VSTS in multiple tenants?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So far I understand that it is possible to deploy multiple web-apps / databases by creating various release environments in VSTS, so I can deploy to multiple clients at the same time. But I see that this is not a formidable way, because if I want to add one more task to the deploy process and want to replicate to other environments, this becomes complicated. I believe there should be some way to just deploy one setup and create a list of environments, one for each tenant, so that it could create a single task that would suit all tenants.

Is there such a configuration in VSTS? Or do they recommend some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate a sequence of tasks into a single reusable task that can be added to each environment of release definition.

More information: [Task Groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/task-groups)

Comment: Hello starain-MSFT, I think that's what I need. Just a doubt, the correct one is to use several of it in a single environment or an environment for each tenant? In the case of the latter would be a "single process" but from what I see, the parameters are visible, already with an environment for each there are variables. I was in doubt.

Comment: It depends on the requirement, for example, you can do them in a single environment if they are dependent on each other, more information: [Environments in Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/environments)